# creating new variables for elements of a data frame given a condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
X <- structure(list(PRCP12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 61L, 0L, 0L, 
8L), PRCP13 = c(0L, 0L, 480L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 310L, 30L, 0L, 0L), 
    PRCP14 = c(0L, 0L, 61L, 150L, 0L, 0L, 99L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PRCP15 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 33L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PRCP16 = c(0L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L), PRCP17 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
    0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PRCP18 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
    8L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PRCP19 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 71L, 0L, 0L, 231L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("PRCP12", "PRCP13", "PRCP14", "PRCP15", 
"PRCP16", "PRCP17", "PRCP18", "PRCP19"), row.names = c(NA, 10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

The real data has a lot more columns and rows.

For each PRCP I want to create a new 0 1 variable.

Right now I'm define a function a running a loop.

```
rainyday <- function(vname, X){
  vname2 = paste('R', vname, sep="")
  vname3 =  paste('PRCP', vname, sep="")
  X[vname2] = 0
  X[vname2][X[vname3]>0.254] = 1
  return(X)
}

for (i in 12:19 ) {
  X = rainyday(i, X)
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: is it necessary to paste the new 0 1 variables to the origin DF? What are you going to do with it in the next step?

Comment: Yes, I need it in the same data frame. I'm going to run some regressions.

Comment: I like Henrik's approach. `X <- cbind(X, (X > 0.254) * 1)` gives you the complete desired dataframe. all you have to do now is to change the column names using `colnames`

Comment: `names(X2) <- c(names(X), paste0("R", gsub("[^0-9]", "", names(X))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Christian Borck + @Richard Scriven answer are perfect for what I wanted to do.

```
X2 <- cbind(X, (X > 0.254) * 1)
names(X2) <- c(names(X), paste0("R", gsub("[^0-9]", "", names(X))))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this:

`X <- sapply(df[12:19],rainyday)`

If this doesnt work u can look at `apply lapply(list) vapply(vector)`

You could also define youre function within the `sapply`

```
X <- sapply(X[12:19],function(i){
  vname2 = paste('R', i, sep="")
  vname3 =  paste('PRCP', i, sep="")
  X[vname2] = 0
  X[vname2][X[vname3]>0.254] = 1
  return(X)
})
```

Since i have no R available to test it i hope there are no typos or errors but they should work.